# Magento doesn't save my catalog_product_set, what can I do?

Tags: magento

I 've installed magento and it seems to work, but if I want to save a new Catalog_product_set with different attributes then I get Internal Error Message with Status Code 500

Does anyone have the same problem?

Thanks in advance
cheers tabaluga

[image]

Comment: have you enabled Error Logging and checked the var/log entries?  Please post back what you find there so we can help diagnose.

Comment: thanks, just edited my questions, there's the log now :)

Answer (score -1):

Your screenshot (and from the looks of it Magento's error page) clips the edge of the error off. Seeing the rest of the error message might be important. Regardless, it looks like Magento is trying to load a config file w/ simplexml, and cannot find that file.

Comment: oh, thanks. My Girlfriend made the screenshot. I'll try the simpleXML file check. 
Thanks

Comment: This should be a comment